# Implementing SSL for Nuxt.js 3.9 in a Production Environment

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ssl, nuxt.js

I'm working on a project that includes a frontend developed with Vue.js/Nuxt.js and a backend powered by Java Spring. For deployment, I've containerized both components into a single Docker image, which is then deployed to a Kubernetes cluster on a separate network. My deployment process involves fetching SSL certificates via a curl command in the entrypoint script, which are intended for use by both the frontend and backend services. I have configured my network to put through the two Ports of the Front- and Backend that share the same IP Address.

I've successfully implemented SSL for the backend service but am encountering difficulties in applying SSL to the frontend. While there is abundant documentation on setting up SSL for local development environments, my goal is to integrate SSL directly into the Nuxt.js build process for deployment within a LAN, bypassing the need for a reverse proxy to manage SSL.

My question is: How can I configure Nuxt.js 3.9 to utilize SSL certificates for a production build, ensuring secure communication without relying on a reverse proxy for SSL termination or management?

**EDIT**

What I tried:

- Using env variables as explained [here](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#entry-point)
- Edit the nuxt.config.js to mimic the way you configure the local https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's documented anywhere on the Nuxt website, but when you inspect the code generated by `nuxi build`, notably `.output/server/chunks/nitro/node-server.mjs` you'll notice a few env variables:

```
const cert = process.env.NITRO_SSL_CERT;
const key = process.env.NITRO_SSL_KEY;
const server = cert && key ? new Server({ key, cert }, toNodeListener(nitroApp.h3App)) : new Server$1(toNodeListener(nitroApp.h3App));
// [...]
const listener = server.listen(path ? { path } : { port, host }, (err) => {
  // [...]
  const protocol = cert && key ? "https" : "http";
  // [...]
  const baseURL = (useRuntimeConfig().app.baseURL || "").replace(/\/$/, "");
  const url = `${protocol}://${addressInfo.family === "IPv6" ? `[${addressInfo.address}]` : addressInfo.address}:${addressInfo.port}${baseURL}`;
  console.log(`Listening on ${url}`);
});
// [...]
```

Therefore, if you want to use SSL with Nitro, you'll just have to define two env variables:

- `NITRO_SSL_CERT` the path to the SSL certificate
- `NITRO_SSL_KEY` the path to the SSL key

You can always [read more about Nitro's use of env variables](https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/runtimes/node#environment-variables)

It should be noted that most people would recommend using a reverse proxy nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had a look into the env variables and created this .env file in the root directory:

```
NITRO_PORT=3000
NITRO_HOST=my-domain.lan
NITRO_SSL_CERT=certs/my-domain.lan.cert
NITRO_SSL_KEY=certs/my-domain.lan.key
```

In my nuxt.config.js file, I've configured the runtime environment variables as follows:

Comment: ```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    // Other configurations...
    runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
            NITRO_HOST: process.env.NITRO_HOST,
            NITRO_PORT: process.env.NITRO_PORT,
            NITRO_SSL_CERT: process.env.NITRO_SSL_CERT,
            NITRO_SSL_KEY: process.env.NITRO_SSL_KEY
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: After running `nuxi build`, the server does not start in HTTPS mode as expected. To debug, I created a simple test script to check the availability of the NITRO_SSL_KEY environment variable:

```js
echo console.log(process.env.NITRO_SSL_KEY) > test.js
node test.js
``` 

The output was undefined, indicating that the environment variable is not being passed through. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: It's not a runtime config, it's what's loaded bby the server through the environment or through `dotenv`. `nuxi build` only builds the server, you run it with `node ./.output/server/index.mjs`. You might need to define these variables when running the server instead of when building it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We have now decided to use a reverse proxy after all.